# Zabbix jmx monitoring of G1

Tags: jmx, zabbix

I asked a question in zabbix forum but it says that someone should approve my question and after one day nothing happened.

I wanna monitor all of the jmx parameters for G1 garbage collector but in tabular items I can't get the value of a specific parameter. 
For example one of the keys I used is as below but it is not supported.

jmx["java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=G1 Old Generation","LastGcInfo.memoryUsageAfterGc.Code Cache.committed"]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use in:

```
name=\"YourName\" >> $jmx["java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=\"G1 Old Generation\"","LastGcInfo.memoryUsageAfterGc.Code Cache.committed"]
```

default template is broken.

This solved my problem, but few items are still unsupported and I don't know how to change them.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed here: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-23948 (planned for 7.0)